# Meaning of “the fears of the fishing-rod of Utopia” in Forgetting by Robert Lynd

Tags: meaning, robert-lynd

Tell me what the following line means from [Forgetting](https://www.thefreshreads.com/forgetting/) by Robet Lynd:

> *The fishing-rod of reality is forgotten by him as he day-dreams over the fears of the fishing-rod of Utopia.*

Especially, “the fears of the fishing-rod of Utopia”.

Comment: For questions asking about the meaning of a specific quote, it is better for the asker to share whatever they have already come up with, and the exact problems they have with understanding the quote. The more detailed your question is, the more detailed (in general) the answers will be.

Comment: You need to link or post the entire poem.  I could give you an interpretation, but hesitate to do so without being able to see the full text.

Comment: @DukeZhou: the whole essay is much too long to post here, but the paragraph containing that line would be useful. And the line is mistranscribed, as well. It's "the *feats* of the fishing-rod of Utopia".

Comment: @Gallifreyan `citation-needed` We have a great deal of [tag:meaning] questions here which don't include information on "what have you [OP] tried?"

Comment: Can you please add in which work you find this sentence? Is this something from [this Robert Lynd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Wilson_Lynd)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line is [mistranscribed.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22feats+of+the+fishing-rod+of%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS737US737&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_yObe0JfcAhWMn4MKHY_6Bh0Q_AUIECgB&biw=790&bih=431) It is

> ... the feats of the fishing-rod of Utopia.

When *feats* is replaced by *fears*, the line does not make very much sense.

And in case you're still confused, what the actual line means is that he forgets about the real fishing-rod while he's thinking about all the amazing things that the imaginary fishing-rod of Utopia has done.